# Why environment specific file is not read when configuring TypeORM CLI with NestJS?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, dotenv

I am trying to setup TypeORM migrations with NestJS. I have created environment specific file `.env.development`; however, whenever i try to specify the exact file to read variables from `process.env.NODE_ENV` returns `undefined`. Application is dockerized.

`Dockerfile.development`:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
```

`docker-compose.development.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nest-api:
    container_name: clean-architecture-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env.development
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules

  db:
    image: postgres:14.1
    restart: always
    container_name: clean-architecture-db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    env_file:
      - .env.development
    volumes: 
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.4
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 8080:80
    volumes:
    - /data/pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    env_file:
    - .env.development
    # environment:
    #   PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
    #   PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root

volumes:
  postgres:
    name: clean-architecture-db
```

`.env.development`

```
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
POSTGRES_DB=nestjs
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
SERVER_PORT=3000
```

`typeOrm.config.ts` - Here `process.env.NODE_ENV` returns undefined

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` });

const configService = new ConfigService();

export default new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: configService.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
  port: configService.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
  username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
  password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
  database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
  entities: [],
});
```

`package.json` scripts:

```
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "NODE_ENV=development nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/main",
    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli",
    "typeorm:run-migrations": "npm run typeorm migration:run -- -d ./src/config/typeOrm.config.ts",
    "typeorm:generate-migration": "npm run typeorm -- -d .src/config/typeOrm.config.ts migration:generate ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
    "typeorm:create-migration": "npm run typeorm -- migration:create ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name"
```

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Z2W.png)

Why is this happening?

I tried using only .env file and it works fine. I also tried using cross-env to pass the variable but that also didnt work

Answer (score 0):

`NODE_ENV` by default, is unset. There's no `NODE_ENV` in your `.env.development` file, so when you read `process.env.NODE_ENV` it's undefined. To ensure `NODE_ENV` is set, either add it to `.env.development` or add an `environment` key to the `nest-api` service

Comment: I did add `NODE_ENV` to `.env.development`; however, value is still undefined. What do you mean add an `environment` key to `nest-api` service?

Comment: [A docker compose service can explicitly set environment variables using the `environment` key](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#environment). So you could do something like `environment: NODE_ENV: development` (properly formatted to yml) and set the value that way

Comment: I updated the code for docker-compose and still value is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - Needed to specify CLI commands in package.json like this:

```
"typeorm:dev": "NODE_ENV=development ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
"migration:generate:dev": "npm run typeorm:dev -- -d ./type-orm.config.ts migration:generate ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name"
```